# How to specify which css files to load in Sharepoint:CssLink when using themes

Tags: css, theme

I noticed that the css being loaded by CssLink differs depending on which page is being loaded. For example, when I load the _layouts/prjsetng.aspx page, it loads:

- ~/_catalogs/theme/themed/7D16DABB/layouts-9C6B8173.css
- ~/_catalogs/theme/themed/7D16DABB/corev4-8A0ABD2F.css

Then when I try to load my home page, the following gets loaded:

- ~/_catalogs/theme/themed/7D16DABB/search-7E1AFF02.css
- ~/_catalogs/theme/themed/7D16DABB/corev4-8A0ABD2F.css

My question is, how do I control this behavior? In my home page, I need a style that is defined in layouts-9C6B8173.css but for some reason, it is not getting loaded.

Comment: why you wanna load it for ?

Comment: we have legay web parts that make use of the `~/_controltemplates/InputFormSection.ascx` user controls. These controls are dependent on css styles defined in the layouts css file

Answer (score 0):

Try to registering your css using,

```
<SharePoint:CSSRegistration name= "<%$SPrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/~language/Core Stypes/Band.css%>" runat="server"/>
```

[CSS Registration MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.cssregistration.aspx)

Hope it helps.